# How do people design this type of design?

Tags: adobe-photoshop

[image]

Ok so how would someone design this invitation and produce it digitally? Would they paint this watercolor first and then scan it in and edit it in photoshop? Or would they use photoshop or some other program to paint it?

My friend wants her wedding invitation to be similar to this but I don't even know how I would acheive the watercolor and then turn it digitally to be reproduced. Any ideas? What would you do?

Thanks for the help!

Comment: definitely looks like a real-world painting, to me. That's then had the frame and text added digitally.

Answer (score 1):

Real painting, of course is fine, but it requires serious effort and talent.

In Photoshop you can use fake art filters to convert flowers to look out painted.  Even imported clipart flowers may bend under these filters. There are some filters in PS included.

Third party plugins can be found. There are free ones and commercial. I have tried Topaz Labs stuff (Simplify, Restyle). Frames are available as clipart (both photos and vector graphic) At least texts are useful to be started in vector graphics program (Illustrator ot thatlike) Metallic glow is available as effect. Slight feel of oldiness and weariness is best achieved in photoshop - filters again. Consistent colors in Photoshop, too.

This design probably takes a day or more to be replicated or adapted into a new design well enough to be shown. The replication job also needs some serious artistic talent. Bare skill on available tools is a must, but it's not enough. Without artistic talent you simply do not make things consistent and not seeming like they are in a wrong place.

ADDENDUM: An example of fake art filtering and the original, too. Details are simplified, blue background and some twigs are swept off to make space, painted strokes are applied and a canvas texture is added.

[image]

[image]

Comment: I love the filter example above, but I'm going to also give my opinion that the invitation the original questioner posted is a real, true, paint-on-paper watercolor with pen and ink touches.

Comment: not denying. But a photo of real painting is needed and taking the elements from it must not be forbidden. This may be considered as personal use - so no troubles, if no uncontrolled distribution happens.

Answer (score 1):

The background looks to me like a real watercolour painting. If so, someone has scanned it, and added the other elements on top in an application such as InDesign. If that is a photograph of a printed invitation, it looks like the printing process has also included some gold foil blocking.

Answer (score 0):

I think that the easiest way to achieve something similar is, for example, to look what [Freepik offers](http://www.freepik.com/index.php?goto=2&searchform=0&k=watercolor%20flowers). They have a lot of quality stuff available for free. This is what I would do if I wasn't too good at painting.

Answer (score -2):

Check out Those tutorials which explains how to get similar effects in full details:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=j6giiWLtjII
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Gr-69AK4g7E

Comment: Welcome to Graphic Design! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.